# Electron-Current Relationship

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, electric-current

I have a rather simple conceptual question that I cannot seem to find a straightforward answer to online. My question is "Does increasing the amount of electrons or increasing the speed of the electrons increase the current?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drift_velocity

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Since current density equals $nqv$ (with a number density $n$ of charges $q$ with speed $v$), then increasing $n$ or $v$ will increase the current density.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, since current is $\frac{charge}{time}$, increasing the number of electrons or their speed would result in increased amperage.